# Capture system audio output with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, audio-streaming

Is there a way in javascript or is there a nodejs module, that I can use to capture the output of a system (win/osx). For example, if a user is playing something via iTunes/MPlayer (any music player), I can capture the audio stream that's going to the speakers (output) and send it over the web?

Comment: There is no cross-platform method for this.  The APIs between Windows and OSX are different.  On Windows, you can only capture this audio on Windows Vista or later.  Even then, I've found its easiest in Windows to use a loopback audio driver so that you can use the standard audio capture methods.  I'm not sure of the APIs on OSX, but I know it is directly possible there.

Comment: Ever have any luck with this? I'm wanting to achieve the same thing. Looking at this module for OSX: https://www.npmjs.com/package/osx-audio

Comment: @JoeSloth unfortunately no, It seems that unless you have a native application running on the OS you can't hook into the system wide output. That node module looks something to keep your eyes on though. Do let me know if you find anything concrete.

Comment: I sort of came up with a solution. I have that osx-audio pulling in audio from the input on my mac. I had to download another app called SoundFlower that can route my computers output audio into its input. I was able to stream my Mac's audio over the internet. Even hooked up my record player to my mac and was able to stream that as well

Comment: @JoeSloth yeah that's what I meant with the native application. The soundflower approach works but sadly in my use case that wasn't an option. I'm glad it worked out for you though.

Answer (score 8):

I'm about to start some dev work on a similar project but was having issues getting node-core-audio to install so I had to find a different module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/naudiodon looks to be a good replacement and it installs just fine. Will update with my findings after I've had some time to play around with it.

**Update:**

For my project, I wanted to run spectrum analysis on the system audio out. I ended up using Soundflower and SoundflowerBed to setup audio routing. Once I had that working, I was able to use naudiodon to record the raw audio data.

This was tested in Node 8.17.0, with my fork of naudiodon which removed console logging on buffer overflow because it messed with my terminal UI.
My fork is available here if you want, but I don't think I did anything specific for this to work.

`github:psnyder/naudiodon#feature/dont-write-to-console-on-buffer-overflow`

I recommend you run this line by line in the node console after installing the required packages.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const portAudio = require('naudiodon');

// Use this to find out the device id for soundflower
console.log(portAudio.getDevices());

// create audio io instance
const ai = new portAudio.AudioIO({
  inOptions: {
    channelCount: 2,
    sampleFormat: portAudio.SampleFormat16Bit,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    deviceId: 2, // choose id for Soundflower (2CH)
    closeOnError: true,
  }
});
const ws = fs.createWriteStream('rawAudio.raw');
ai.pipe(ws);
ai.start();
// Wait a while as you record the audio in -- check your sound levels in SoundflowerBed, etc.
// When you are done...
ai.quit();
```

Now in Audacity, you can File -> Import -> Raw Data and check for an audio waveform.

Comment: did you ever get system audio working?

Comment: @BenRacicot Just updated my answer with my experiences. Hope its helpful!

Comment: Is there any way to adjust how small buffers it can deliver? As it is now naudonion seems to deliver buffers at around 16000 bytes each when recording mono at 44100 and that is way too much latency to do real time processing or streaming of the sound.

Answer (score 2):

This might go some way to doing what you want: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-core-audio