# Reading system sound directly from node

Tags: javascript, node.js

What i'm looking for: A method to read system audio levels

What i've tried: I've looked into numerous node packages without finding what i want

Scenario: You want a node script running, and simply want to be notified when the system sound reaches above a certain threshold. For example when you get a message on facebook. The node script should notice that the audio levels are above 50% for a second and console.log that. Is this possible? I imagine this is not something native javascript can do. Are there any modules available where this is a feature?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Related: [Capture system audio output with Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033583/capture-system-audio-output-with-nodejs)

Comment: They recommend naudiodon in that thread. naudiodon can read and write the system sound to a .wav file. But that doesn't help me much. I want to monitor the percentage of sound from 0-100% live

Comment: I haven't tried to do this by using node. Interesting idea and definitely possible. You just need to do _more_ searching.

Comment: thank you, i'll continue my search while also hoping that someone here can help me